# Unable to populate system environment values in springboot application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I am trying to access environment values in the application.properties file. The environment variables have been set in my system variables (Windows Environment Variables), say SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME. But when I try to access that variable in my application.properties file by using:

```
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
```

That value is not getting populated. Rather I get a error:

> 2020-04-24 15:08:29.620  WARN 9892 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}"

It is as if that ${...} is getting passed as a string completely. I am a beginner to this, so kindly point out the error if I am doing any. I am so far unable to find my mistake from the solutions to similar problems posted here.

NOTE: The database URL is hardcoded that's why I am getting password authentication error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that at all!

```
spring.datasource.username
```

will be overwritten by the environment variable (User Variables) SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME

So you can remove this entry from the application.properties ( and restart your IDE in case the environment variables were added recently )

Please read more about configuration in the Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Ok. But now, I am not getting my database username. Instead it is returning me this error:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "amiya"`

And, If I remove my spring.database.url it is returning this error:
`Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.`

Seems like it is unable to find my env variables.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this post while searching for this very issue. Instead of populating a null or blank in the absence of some environment variables, spring populates the placeholder text as a string in value of the property. Since in the absence of environment variable, one would always prefer a default value like null or "" instead of the placeholder text itself, you could provide this value by using a colon, as shown below.

```
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME : null}
```

As for your issue, though it's pretty old one, you were getting the username after you removed the entry from application.properties. It's just that this user wasn't correctly authenticated, maybe because the password wasn't provisioned or set in environment variables.